# Pressing right alt causes shutdown

Tags: windows-10, laptop, alt

I have an issue with almost* clean installation of Windows 10 Pro (version 1607) on Lenovo Thinkpad T420 which is in our domain.
Issue is if I press **right <kbd>alt</kbd>** for more than (about) 0.5s the laptop starts shutting down! (But if you have open some file like text file, windows waits for answer from the program)

No other computer (sometimes the same type of laptop) in our domain has same issue either it has Windows 10 or not.
Btw I want to dodge reinstall, because I just installed all the beautiful and awesome windows updates (in work with limited connection it consumed like 3-4 days).

*I have installed VLC, 7zip, Nitro Reader and Eset and through troubleshooting uninstalled Synaptics SW.

Some info from event viewer (other events look normal and I think this is critical, because it's the event just in time of issue)

> -System
>
> - Provider
>
>   [ Name]  Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power
>     [ Guid] {331C3B3A-2005-44C2-AC5E-77220C37D6B4}
>
>   EventID 109
>
>   Version 0
>
>   Level 4
>
>   Task 103
>
>   Opcode 0
>
>   Keywords 0x8000400000000404
> - TimeCreated
>
>   [ SystemTime]  2017-03-01T11:06:16.256891400Z
>
>   EventRecordID 2367
>
>   Correlation
> - Execution
>
>   [ ProcessID]  4     [ ThreadID]  372
>
>   Channel System
>
>   Computer xxx.yyy.zz
> - Security
>
>   [ UserID]  S-1-5-18
>
>   - EventData
>
>   ShutdownActionType 6
>
>   ShutdownEventCode 16
>
>   ShutdownReason 0

The Shutdown reason is something like "(Power)Button or cover"

I don't think it's HW issue, just cant imagine how could be <kbd>rAlt</kbd> key connected to power button.

What have I tried and didn't solve problem:

- Clean Boot (without any services but microsoft)
- Safe boot
- Reinstalling keyboard drivers
- Physicaly clean keyboard
- Conneting second keyboard - <kbd>rAlt</kbd> worked right on this keyboard
- Cold restart

If you have any hints, suggestions or whole solution I would be very grateful.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem solved.**

It was HW issue. I have changed keyboard and all keys run correctly.